# Keras: How to design the Input Layer and Shape of neural network?

Tags: input, neural-network, keras, shapes, layer

I want to design a neural network in keras, but I'm not sure about how to create the input shape of the input layer.

My Input_Data looks like the following (y data not shown here):

```
ID    Parameter    Value
A     1            4
A     2            1,5
A     3            81,6
B     1            4,2
B     2            1,7
B     3            82,1
C     1            4,1
C     2            1,6
C     3            80,8
```

So each ID is described by the same three parameters (1,2,3) and their values.

-> My idea was to create the model like this:

```
model = Sequential()     
model.add(Dense(3,input_dim=3, activation='relu'))
```

Because I thought, if I have 3 input features, I need input_dim=3 and 1 node for one input feature. 
But I found some examples where they used 3 input features (input_dim = 3), but 10 nodes in the input layer, so I'm confused about the relation between nodes and features now.

--> Which input_shape or input_dim do I have to use? Is it correct to use 3 nodes?

I'm thankful for any help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
model = Sequential()     
model.add(Dense(3,input_dim=3, activation='relu'))   
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

This should work, I added a hidden layer of 10 units (use whatever you think you  will need) and then I added an output layer of 1 unit, since you just want one output and chose sigmoid as an output, but use whatever you need.

If you have more questions feel free to ask.

Comment: So the input_dim=3 is correct?
And if I want to train my model now, I just have to use the values column, right?
So I can just compile the model and pass the scaled values like this?:

model.compile(Adam(lr=0.001), loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy]
model.fit(scaled_train_values,scaled_train_labels,batch_size=10,epochs=20, shuffle = True)

Comment: The number is correct yes. For training you will have to feed each row of data.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

But when you say each row of data, are you saying that I have to use all the columns (ID, Parameter,Value)?

Comment: Yes, each input should be a list which has three elements `[ID, Parameter, Value]`. Your first input should be: [A, 1, 4]. By seeing your dataset I recommend you to translating you first column to numbers, so it will be like A -> 0, B -> 1, C -> 3. Is your third column a list of elements?

Comment: Ah ok! But why do I need the first and second column? I thought when I put all the values of parameter 1 to the first neuron, of parameter 2 to the second neuron and so on it would be fine?
And my third column is a number (float), sorry I should have put a '.' for seperating

Comment: You will use `model.fit()` for training, the first parameter you will have to put is a 2D list of your data, having 3 columns (ID, Parameter, Value ) and as many rows as data you have.

Comment: But if I compare it to all the image recognition examples, where one image (without any description like my ID, or Parameter) has **28x28 Pixels =784 values**, then it was used: `input_shape= (784,)`
So I have everytime 3 values which describe my ID. So shouldn't I use just these values?
Sorry, that I'm asking again, but I don't understand your explanation yet

Comment: Okay I read your post again, and then saw what you mean. The data is not organized as I thought, you will have `input_shape = (3 , )` and the first input will be: `[4, 1.5, 81.6]`. I thought that `ID` and `Parameter` were features too.